# Exporting external sheets to PDF without using Activesheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export-to-pdf

I have a two part problem

I have a list of sheets and tabs that i want to create a PDF out of. Since I cannot create 1 PDF at once, I have decided to create many PDF's and merge them in one step. Now here's my problem.

1. Generally .exportAsFixedformat is used with 'Activesheet', I am trying to use this directly,
2. Also even when I do this with Activesheet the parameters 'From' and 'To' it gives me problem

   ```
       Do
       PrintWB = .Cells(i, 2) 'sheetpath + workbookname
       sheetname = .Cells(i, 3) 'Name of Tab
       Frompage = .Cells(i, 4) 'From
       Topage = .Cells(i, 5) 'To

       Workbook(PrintWB).Sheets(sheetname).ExportAsFixedFormat _
       Type:=xlTypePDF, _
       Filename:="C:\Rough\" & x & ".pdf", _
       Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
       IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
       IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
       OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
       From:=Frompage,_
       To:=Topage
       Loop While .Cells(i - 1, 2) = .Cells(i, 2)
   ```

Short note : The Do-while loop helps me from not opening and closing the same sheet again and again, just in case one of the sheet has multiple tabs to be printed, so just ignore that

Right now we print a bunch of documents and file them after creating a small booklet, if I am able to consolidate a PDF, this will save a lot of paper.

Answer (score 0):

It was having a spelling mistake in WOrkbook, there should have been an 's' in the end...so it'd be workbooks and it worked!!